# wordpress default markup for html editor

Tags: wordpress

Is there a plugin or something that allows me to load some specific markup when i am going to add new page.

For Example when i press **Add new page** and click on html editor it should already have some markup like

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

Also other problem i m facing with html editor is that "enter" to paragraph tag itself. I want it to work like pure html editor like notepad. It should not translate anything on its own. Is it possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your functions.php should help.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );

    function my_editor_content( $content ) {

        if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/yourtheme/default-content.html')){$content = file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/yourtheme/default-content.html');}else{$content = "Enter your content here.";}

        return $content;
    }
```